# Как потестировать stdin, stdout JavaScript/Node.js для решения задач?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdin

Решаю тренировочные задачи для поступления на стажерскую программу в одну из компаний.

На сайте решение для автоматического тестирования нужно писать с помощью стандартных потоков ввода/вывода.

Пример данных для ввода:

```
5 5

1  4  9  16  25

2
```

Вывод:

```
24
```

Пытаюсь писать ответ согласно примеру, приложенному на сайте:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

let total = 0;
process.stdin.on('end', () => { console.log(total); process.exit(0); });
rl.on('line', function (data) {
        data = data.split(' ');

        const countAndTime = parseInt(data[0]) || 0 //Я предполагаю, что каждая из переменных - массив 
        const floors = parseInt(data[1]) || 0
        const outgoing = parseInt(data[2]) || 0

        const howMuchMinutes = (countAndTime, floors, outgoing) => {            
            let maxTime 
            
            //тут решение самой задачи
            
            return maxTime 
        }
        
        total = howMuchMinutes(countAndTime, floors, outgoing)   
});
```

В качестве ответа получаю вердикт системы: "**Partial Solution - Частичное решение**".

Причём такой ответ я получаю не только с этой задачей, но и со всеми остальными.

Если решать задачу с обычным выводом в console.log, подставляя на вводе пример данных, ответ правильный.

Я не понимаю, дело в моих решениях или же в том, что я неправильно пишу ввод/вывод?
Я даже не уверена, действительно ли данные приходят в виде массивов, как я предполагаю.

Есть ли способ проверить правильность ввода/вывода? Быть может есть какие-то сервисы, которые выполняют  подобное тестирование, но выводя на экран то, что выводят потоки... Или можно написать такой тест самой?

Если моя реализация stdin\stdout чтобы получить массивы в качестве данных неверная, я была бы благодарна, если бы вы написали правильную.